# Rewrite directories using mod_rewrite but keeping query strings

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm wanting to rewrite Word Press urls using mod_rewrite in my .htaccess file in the following ways:

```
http://blog.com/content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css
```

to

```
http://blog.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css
```

and

```
http://blog.com/inc/css/admin-bar.css?ver=20110622
```

to

```
http://blog.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css?ver=20110622
```

and

```
http://blog.com/admin/post.php?post=1&amp;action=edit
```

to

```
http://blog.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=1&amp;action=edit
```

I'm trying to hide the fact that this website is using Word Press, and all links have been rewritten on the fly using PHP. However I want the server to rewrite the links back to the correct Word Press ones as above.

In case it helps, I've prepended a file (in my php.ini file) to the Wordpress index.php file which calls the ob_start(); function and then appended the following file:

```
<?php
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$html = str_replace("wp-content", "content", $html);
$html = str_replace("wp-admin", "admin", $html);
$html = str_replace("wp-includes", "inc", $html);
echo $html; 
?>
```

Some people may question why I want to hide the fact that we're using Word Press. There are many reasons (security being one of them) but that's not really the point to this question.

What code can I add to my .htaccess file that would let me rewrite the urls but keeping the correct query strings such as ?ver=20110622 or ?post=1&action=edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[QSA]` flag will maintain the query string when rewriting the URL. Example:

```
RewriteRule ^content/(.*?) wp-content/$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Unfortunately I am getting a 404 so it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Please don't copy paste, it is an example. You need to modify it to work with your server.

Comment: I didn't quite copy and paste, but I it should work on my server. I assume that the ^content/(.*?) bit will pick up any url starting with "content/" and rewrite in its entirity to wp-content/...

Comment: That is what it does. Try adding the `L` flag to the above rule (will look like `[L,QSA]`). This will ensure no other rewrite rule is interfering.

Comment: I think Word Press is interfering with this which is very frustrating. You've answered my specific question which is great, but I can't get it to work in my instance. I'll have a play around and see if I can see what the issue is. I'll mark your answer as the accepted one since it does answer my question. Thanks.

Comment: @baritoneuk Please show content of your .htaccess with the above rule in it (update your question). Most likely you have placed this rule in wrong place (**order of rules matters**).